# ¿Reposicionar una ventana y traer al frente?

Tags: java, smartgwt

He creado una ventana que muestra una animacion de loading que dice *"Cargando siguiente dato"*.

Mi idea es que cuando el cliente pulse cierto botón aparezca la ventana con una animación durante la carga de un registro y luego desaparezca.
El caso es que quiero que la ventana aparezca en medio de la pantalla y no soy capaz.
He probado con los métodos **setRect** y **moveTo** y aunque me colocan la ventana donde quiero me la muestran por detrás del layout, así que no se ve.
Si no uso **setRect** o **moveTo** la ventana se ve bien pero arriba a la izquierda de la pantalla.

La pregunta es si estoy usando los métodos que no son para reposicionar la pantalla, si hay algún método para traer la pantalla al frente o si no estoy haciendo las cosas en el orden que debería.

EDIT: Escribiendo la pregunta me acabo de dar cuenta después de llamar a *animateShow()* lo que hago es ponerme a **cargar un layout nuevo, que posiblemente esté tapando la ventana**, asique **lo que necesito es una forma de traer la ventana al frente**.

EDIT2: Clarificar que esta es la Window de la que hablo [com.smartgwt.client.widgets.window](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Window.html)

```
public class Test extends Window{

    private AnimationEffect animacionEntrada;
    private AnimationEffect animacionSalida;

    public Test(){
        setHeight                (125);
        setWidth                 (300);
        setAnimateTime           (300);
        setVisibility            (Visibility.HIDDEN);
        setIsModal               (false);

        HLayout layout = new HLayout();
        layout.setHeight100();
        layout.setWidth100();
        layout.setBackgroundColor("#dfe8f6");

        //Creo otros elementos... no muestro el código
        addItem(layout);

        animacionEntrada = AnimationEffect.FLY;
        animacionSalida  = AnimationEffect.FADE;

        //Intento reposicionar la ventana en el medio
        int alturaNavegador = com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.getClientHeight();
        int y = (alturaNavegador/2) - (getHeight()/2);

        setRect(50, y, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public void mostrar(){
        animateShow(animacionEntrada, new AnimationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void execute(boolean earlyFinish){
                Timer t = new Timer(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        animateHide(animacionSalida);
                    }
                };
                t.schedule(1250);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: El método `setComponentZOrder`, te podría servir;
Espero haberte ayudado